# Automate copying part of a text and paste it somewhere else on the same line for multiple lines

Tags: windows-10, textfiles

I have text files with some information I want to copy from one place and paste somewhere else on the same line. For instance, I have something like:

```
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie", UniqueId = "1110100", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie", UniqueId = "1110110", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Mango Smoothie", UniqueId = "1110120", More random text};
.
.
.
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie", UniqueId = "2000110", More random text};
```

and I want the numbers after UniqueId to be copied and placed at the end of **Smoothie** on the same line like so

```
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie 1110100", UniqueId = "1110100", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie 1110110", UniqueId = "1110110", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Mango Smoothie 1110120", UniqueId = "1110120", More random text};
.
.
.
Random text here { Name = "Tropical Smoothie 2000110", UniqueId = "2000110", More random text};
```

As long as there is a space after the words that are in quotes after *Name* and then the UniqueId numbers. The name can be anything, the UniqueId is unique for each line.

So using the first line as example, in a text editor I would highlight 1110100 and copy it and put a space after **Smoothie** then paste. Then I would do the same thing for the next line and so on.
Can this task be automated somehow for each line? I'll try any script or Windows program.
Even something that does "for each line copy 7 digits after 3rd double-quotes and paste before 2nd double-quotes" or some such would work.

Comment: that text looks suspiciouly... how to say it... a programmer kinda thing. Does `fgets()` sound familiar to you?, if not, well, I'm sorry, I don't know any Windows program that solves this specific problem. Can you compile code by any chance?

Comment: No I can't compile. This example is text from a .cs file but I'm not looking for a programming solution as I have other text files that I want to be able to do the same thing with.

Comment: What tools do you have avaliable? cmd, python, bash?

Comment: Yes I'll try any Windows program, script or app like cmd, Powershell, VBS or download any tool. Not familiar with fgets @JennyT-Type.

Comment: `fgets()` is a C function that reads a line from a file in put it in a string, I only mention it cause I thought that you might know a little bit of programming, (C is a programming language). I asked you if you can compile cause I was willing to write a program for you to compile in your machine, but setting a cross-compiler just for you, well, not so much. though I'm giving it a though.

Comment: Is cross-compiling easy and you could write a program that could do what I wanted, JennyT-Type ? And @dmb you could do something with python if I installed it?

Comment: @joetex72 I edit lots of txt in such ways with python3, I recommend you to learn it. I’m here lo learn and help others learn.

Comment: I installed python 3.4.4 @dmb. What next?

Comment: @J.A.P Yes, I do I've been using regex and Notepad++ but for specifics, for mass processing python or awk is my thing. But also, I can't see any sort of try and fail in the __Question__, he is just asking for a script, which in StackExchange sites is frowned upon. That's why I suggested some tools.

Comment: First, thanks @dmb for offering to help and you are right, I wasn't looking for a specific way of accomplishing the task. I also was not aware that scripts were frowned upon. J.A.P, I did ask on StackExchange but this site was more suited for the question as I wasn't looking for a programming solution. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for, so thank you very much. I marked the answer up but my level is too low for it to show. Thanks again to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Still would like to learn how to do it in Python if you don't mind @dmb .Oh, and I meant StackOverflow above, not StackExchange.

Comment: @joetex72 You can use regex in Python as well, but reading/writing the file involves a little bit of programming. Your particular file also looks like JSON, which means you could parse it as a JSON object to make the changes instead of using regex. However, programming is more complex, if you want to learn how to do something like this in Python I suggest you follow a basic Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You asked the same question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775419/copy-portion-of-text-in-a-file-and-paste-somewhere-else-on-the-same-line-within/) where I just wrote you an answer. I am supplying the same answer here as well.*

You can accomplish what you are asking by using any text editor that supports Regex. In this example, I will be using Notepad++. First I will describe what to do, then after I will explain what the Regex does.

**Example**

1. Open the file with `Notepad++`.
2. Press `Ctrl+F` to bring up the `Search and Replace` window.
3. Make sure to check the box named `Wrap around`
4. Select `Regular expression` under `Search Mode`
5. Under `Find What:` insert `Name = "(.*)", UniqueId = "(\d+)"`
6. Under `Replace with:` insert `Name = "$1 $2", UniqueId = "$2"`
7. Press `Replace all` once.

[image: Npp-with-regex]

**Understanding the regex**

- `()` these characters represent a group that you want to capture.
- `$1` represent the first group that you marked with `()`
- `$2` same thing but it takes the second group.
- `\d` matches `any digit`. `+` after a digit means, match one or more digits.
- `.` matches `any character`. `*` after the dot means match zero or more characters.

In the search example `Name = "(.*)", UniqueId = "(\d+)"` we have two groups. Matching the content in between the quotes of Name and UniqueId.

In the replace example `Name = "$1 $2", UniqueId = "$2"`, we are using these groups to replace what we match with something new. The new is, in this case, the contents of group `$1` and group `$2`.